# Uploading new build for released application iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app store application has gone through review process, I made a release now it shows the `Ready to Sale` status. At this point we have figured out a small bug which we have fixed.

I have uploaded new build version with this fix on iTunes connect via my XCode. I am able to see this build. Now I want to submit this new build for app review. I don't see an option for submission of this build for app review. Do I need to create new version for this ? Can't I upload new build for same version under ready to sale for submission to review.

Also I want to change some of the screen shots I don't see options for this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading a new build, you need to create a new version on iTunes. After creating a new version you can submit it with your latest build & also update all the details which you desire & all those will be reviewed & made live once apple review those.

Comment: Can't I add new build under existing version ?

Comment: @pcj No you can't do that. You can create an incremental version say 1.1 & do your changes in that. That will work the same as it will prompt user as update. You can also mention "Minor bug fixes" in what's new in this version, there is no harm in that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new version of your app to do that. You can not change an existing, 'ready for sale' app.

Comment: Can't I add new build under existing version ?